# get latest 5 status updates using Facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm new to the Facebook SDK and i need to retrieve the 5 latest status update from a companies Facebook page. I have no idea where to start or what to do so any help will be highly appreciated.

this is what i was able to get from developer.facebook.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId: [my app id],
                channelUrl: 'http://localhost:30125/Default.aspx', 
                status: false,                                 
                xfbml: true
            });

            // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here



        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the login code mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/  in the **Add the login code** part.

Then edit your `testAPI()`-

```
function testAPI() 
{
   console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
   FB.api('/me', function(response) 
   {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
   });
   FB.api('/cocacola/feed?limit=5', function(response) 
   {
      for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++)
      { 
         console.log(i + " : " + response.data[i].message);
      }
   });
}
```

[Live Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Ffeed%3Flimit%3D5)

to get the list of parameters `feed` supports: [Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

The implementation is quite simple and self-understood, let me know if you find any difficulty using this.

Comment: So should i use an access token instead of an appId?

eg. FB.init({
                access_token: [access token]',
                channelUrl: 'http://localhost:30125/Default.aspx', 
                status: false,                                 
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true// Look for social plugins on the page
            });

Comment: No, you have to write `appId` only in the `FB.init()`

Comment: i get this error/warning when i run it: The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating. Any idea why?

Comment: `The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating` - this is normal, you can ignore it!

Comment: But i dont get any results in the Console and i have no idea why. please look at my code http://jsfiddle.net/z6jha/1/ and let me know what im doing wrong

Comment: `access_token: 'AppID',` - this is invalid line - use appId instead

Comment: I cant see: `<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>` too; why dont you simply copy and paste the code from the link provided